# Is there a way to turn my data from string variables to numeric?

Tags: database, string, stata, numeric

I imported my data into Stata, and the program is reading some of the variables as strings, but not all of them. And I cannot understand what I did wrong, as some variables are being read as numbers. Is there a way in Stata to turn the string into numeric?

Comment: Are you importing from CSV, excel or something else? You can try something like `tostring {varlist}, replace`, and Stata will tell you if columns contain nonnumeric values. In that case you will need to do some cleaning.

Comment: You can use `destring` to create a numeric variable from a string variable, see `help destring`. It is likely however that your string variables contain values that cannot be read as a number.

Answer (score 1):

`destring` is intended for this situation, but the real question is why Stata read your variables as string when you think they should be numeric.

Some of the reasons commonly met are

1. There is metadata in your data, especially if the data were read in from a file that has spent time in a spreadsheet. Rows of header information or endnotes can cause this problem.
2. A missing data code has been used that Stata doesn't recognise, say `NA` for missing.
3. Decimal points are indicated by say commas, not stops or periods.

The options of `destring` are often critical, as you may need to spell out what should be done. So, study the help for `destring`.

If a variable to you should be numeric, but it's not clear why not, something like

```
tab myvar if missing(real(myvar))
```

shows the kinds of values of `myvar` that can't be converted easily. Very often it becomes clear quickly that there is one repeated problem for which there is one overall fix.